# Write a consequence of children tags in one line into csv file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: csv, tags, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import json
p = """
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Company Name</th>
<th>Symbol</th>
<th>Market</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Shares</th>
<th>Offer Amount</th>
<th>Date Priced</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.nasdaq.com" id="two">EXFO INC.</a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.nasdaq.com" id="two">EXFO</a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.nasdaq.com" id="two">NASDAQ</a></td>
<td>$26</td>
<td>7,000,000</td>
<td>$182,000,000</td>
<td>6/30/2000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.nasdaq.com">IGO, INC.</a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.nasdaq.com" id="two">MOBE</a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.nasdaq.com" id="two">NASDAQ</a></td>
<td>$12</td>
<td>4,000,000</td>
<td>$48,000,000</td>
<td>6/30/2000</td>
</tr>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(p, 'html.parser')
for ana in soup.find_all('td'):
    if ana.parent.name == 'tr':
    print ana.string
```

Hi!I am trying to write into csv file some data from one site. The desirable outcome is a csv file with

```
EXFO INC.,EXFO,NASDAQ,$26,7,000,000,$182,000,000,6/30/2000
IGO, INC.,MOBE,NASDAQ, $12, 4,000,000,$48,000,000,6/30/2000
```

What I learnt to do for now is getting printed the following

```
EXFO INC.
EXFO
NASDAQ
$26
7,000,000
$182,000,000
6/30/2000
IGO, INC.
MOBE
NASDAQ
$12
4,000,000
$48,000,000
6/30/2000
```

Any ideas how to do this?I just don't know how to put it all into the loop and for every tag "" extract all the "" tags.

Comment: I meant for every tag tr extract all the td tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the table, find the *th* tags inside the *thead* and write then extract all the other rows and write the *td* text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.select_one("table")
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = writer(f)
    wr.writerow([th.text for th in table.select("thead  th")])
    for row in table.find_all("tr"):
        data = [td.text for td in row.find_all("td")]
        if data:
            wr.writerow(data)
```

Which would give you:

```
Company Name,Symbol,Market,Price,Shares,Offer Amount,Date Priced
EXFO INC.,EXFO,NASDAQ,$26,"7,000,000","$182,000,000",6/30/2000
"IGO, INC.",MOBE,NASDAQ,$12,"4,000,000","$48,000,000",6/30/2000
```

Another way would be to find all the *tr's* and index/slice:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

rows = soup.select("table tr")
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = writer(f)
    wr.writerow([th.text for th in rows[0].find_all("th")])
    for row in rows[1:]:
        data = [td.text for td in row.find_all("td")]
        wr.writerow(data)
```

Whatever approach, you want to go through all *tr* tags so you can extract all the associated *td* tags inside each tr to group your data into rows.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. It has helped me a lot!